# UnCSS not able to find stylesheet in backbone application

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js, sass, marionette

So my application is much in need of a CSS clean up. I did some research and I came across uncss, which seems like the best option out there so far.

A little about my application:

- It's a backbone.marionette app
- I use Sass
- I compile all my assets into `public/js/app.js` and `public/css/main.css` using the amazing tool [brunch.io](http://brunch.io/)

I've tried running both the command line tool offered in [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss), and the [brunch extension](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch) of uncss. But each time I run the process, I get this error:

```
Error: UnCSS: no stylesheets found
```

Also, if anyone has any experience with brunch, this is how I add the rule to my `config.coffee`:

```
uncss:
  options:
    csspath: 'css/main.css'
    htmlroot: 'public'
  files: ['index.html']
```

Anyone come across this error? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using a framework like backbone.marionette?

Comment: Does this comment help at all? https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/46#issuecomment-33177631

Comment: Did you run UnCSS on the compiled CSS files? It doesn't look like UnCSS can read Sass.

Comment: @collin The comment helped conceptually, but it still isn't finding the file.

Comment: @KatieK, I'm trying to run it on my compiled main.css file.