# UnCSS setup with Brunch

Tags: brunch, bootstrap-4, uncss

Using [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) as my build-tool for a front-end prototype, I am having difficulty setting up the [UnCSS](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch)-plugin. I installed the [Bootstrap 4](https://github.com/bassjobsen/brunch-bootstrap4)-skeleton for a quick setup, and apart from UnCSS everything is running smoothly.

The error I get on `brunch build --production` is `error: UnCSS: no stylesheets found`. I configured the plugins like this:

```
  plugins:
    sass:
      options:
        includePaths: [
          'bower_components/bootstrap/scss'
        ]
    postcss:
      processors: [
        require('autoprefixer')
      ]
    babel:
      ignore: [
        /^(bower_components|vendor)/
      ]
    uncss:
        options:
            csspath: 'css/app.css'
            htmlroot: 'public'
        files: ['index.html']
```

The source files for the project are located in `app`: `index.html` in `app/assets`, `main.scss` (imports Bootstrap) and `styles.css` in `app/stylesheets`, and `app.js` in `app/javascripts`.

Brunch builds this to a folder named `public`, with styles in `public/css/app.css` and content in `public/index.html`. The question is, what is incorrect about the configuration of UnCSS? My understanding of it is that it works on the CSS output from the build, in which case the paths seem correct.

There is [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598695/uncss-not-able-to-find-stylesheet-in-backbone-application) from 2014 asking pretty much the same thing, but it was never answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not considered looking at the GitHub issues, wherein [one specifically addressed this](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch/issues/1). In essence, as suggested by [@1951FDG](https://github.com/1951FDG):

```
  plugins:
    uncss:
      options:
        ignore: [/\.\bactive\b/]
        ignoreSheets: [/fonts.googleapis/]
      files: ['public/index.html']
```

> ignore: sample regex to ignore '.active' class
>
> ignoreSheets: sample regex to ignore Google fonts

More importantly, this invocation of UnCSS reads the stylesheets linked in `index.html` to find the correct CSS-file, then processes it.